# Get access token from Adwords API with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, google-ads-api

I am using the following gem [adwords-api-ruby](https://github.com/googleads/google-api-ads-ruby), and I have done the following:

```
require 'adwords_api'

class Client
  def initialize
    @adwords = AdwordsApi::Api.new({
      :authentication => {
        :method => 'OAuth2',
        :oauth2_client_id => 'xxxxx',
        :oauth2_client_secret => 'xxxxx',
        :developer_token => 'xxxx',
        :client_customer_id => '5xxxx',
        :user_agent => 'Ruby Sample'
      },
      :service => {
        :environment => 'Production'
      }
    })
  end

  def get_service(name, version)
    return @adwords.service(name, version)
  end
end

client = Client.new
campaign_srv = client.get_service(:CampaignService, nil)
campaigns = campaign_srv.get({:fields => ['Id', 'Name', 'Status']})
```

But I get a:

```
`generate_access_token': AdsCommon::Errors::OAuth2VerificationRequired (AdsCommon::Errors::OAuth2VerificationRequired)
```

I guess is because I don't have an access token.  I am wondering how would I get that access token? Say I want to access multiple API (from my clients), and I would like to have that access token stored in my DB. Is there any way I could do so?

Comment: There is an issue related to this: https://github.com/googleads/google-api-ads-ruby/issues/11

Comment: Yes. I saw. They should document that from my point of view.